# res.render() calls promise twice expressjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, es6-promise

Hello I am still a beginner in Nodejs and MongoDB. When I am running  res.render() function as shown below I get 2 console logs, first with the correct result from mongodb find query and second with null. If I remove res.render() It works properly with only one console.log() output and not the second null.

```
router.get('/:areaslug', (req, res) => {
    // Query results
    let areavar = {}     

    return client.db("AwesomeApartments")
                 .collection("areas")
                 .findOne({slug: req.params.areaslug
    })
    .then((datadb) => {
      // first time shows correct results next it shows null
      console.log(" bug-testing : "+JSON.stringify(datadb));

      //storing result of first query to my object
      areavar = datadb; 

      return client.db("AwesomeApartments")
                   .collection("apartments")
                   .find({area:datadb._id})
                   .toArray()
      })
      .then((apartmentdb) => {
        // Storing results of second query
        areavar.apartments = apartmentdb; 

        //removing this solves the issue
        return res.render('area',areavar); 

       }).catch(err =>       
       {
         console.log(err);

         return;
       })
    });
```

Comment: I would suggest you add `console.log(req.url)` to your code and you can see what exactly is happening.  One guess (if this is top level router) is that you're getting a request for `/favicon.ico` as the browser asks your server for the favicon.  IMO, you should never have a wildcard top level route like this for this and a number of other reasons.

Comment: There are some serious mistakes in your code. You gotta go over the fundamentals first before. You still didn't fully grasp how to use return statements. Unfortunately I wasn't able to answer your question because I think someone has to accept it first. But I would advise you to study more about the basics of node/javascript, then promises.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thank you! After following your suggestion I found that browser was requesting favicon.ico

Comment: FYI, this is just one reason why a top level wildcard route is generally a bad idea.  It really hamstrings any future development if your slug namespace conflicts/overlaps with the site namespace.  They can both be top level, but you should design slugs so that they are unique from top level URL names you might want to use for your site (such as `favicon.ico` or other names used in the presentation of your site).

Answer (score 0):

To those who find their way here,  browser was generating two get requests. First one for query and second one for favicon.ico. Handling favicon.ico request solved this issue.